# Unable to get CSSCount working

Tags: javascript, css, selenium

I was trying to use [this](http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/) blog post. To get count of CSS locators. But of not avail, method is -

```
public static int getCSSCount(String cssLocator) {
    String jsScript = "var cssMatches = eval_css(\"%s\", window.document);cssMatches.length;"; 
    return Integer.parseInt(selenium.getEval(String.format(jsScript, cssLocator))); 
}
```

and the method call -

```
getCSSCount("div[class='team-name'] a");
```

but I always encounter following exception -

> FAILED:
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException:
>   ERROR: Threw an exception:
>   unterminated string literal   at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:262)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.getEval(DefaultSelenium.java:471)

Comment: could you post the html for the css locator you are counting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works well for me...

There appears to be a slight syntactical issue in your CSS identifier...

Try this -

```
getCSSCount("div[class=team-name]");
```

Also, if the elements you are counting are contained within an iframe, ensure that you use a `selenium.selectFrame(...);` to set the focus within that frame.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the code given above and it worked for me. My cssLocator was:

`"div[class=\'callout\'] a"`.

I think problem is due to un-escaped single quote supplied to JavaScript function.